# CVPixelBufferGetAddress returns Nil

Tags: swift, core-graphics, core-video

I am currently trying to get the baseAddress of a CVVideoPixelBuffer but it kept returning nil even when I was able to see that CVVideoPixelBuffer itself was not nil.

```
let baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(cvPixelBuffer, 0) // -> nil =(
```

Answer (score 4):

I found out that the reason is because I was trying to access the pixelBuffer from CPU and therefore requires the CVPixelBuffer's addressed to be locked into a specific address in memory.

```
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(cvPixelBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags.readOnly)
let baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(cvPixelBuffer, 0)
CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(cvPixelBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags.readOnly)
```

This works!